# Eclipse Dynamic Web Project fails to load under WTP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp, struts-1

When trying to run an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project under a Tomcat setup using WTP, it fails with the attached stacktrace.

Checklist

- At the project properties, under "Java EE Module Dependencies" I have checked the "Maven Dependencies"
- At the wtp deploy directory, under lib indeed all dependencies are present (esp. struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar)

On the other hand, if I package with maven and copy the war file under the webapps directory everything is working as normal.

**Specification**

Eclipse Java EE Galileo SR2 (with WTP 3.1.1)

Tomcat 6.0.26

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04-248-10M3025)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01-101, mixed mode)

**stacktrace**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to read TLD "META-INF/tld/struts-html-el.tld" from JAR file "file:/Users/cue/Development/workspace/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpwebapps/ticketing/WEB-INF/lib/struts-el-1.3.10.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagExtraInfo class: org.apache.struts.taglib.html.MessagesTei
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:181)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:182)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:383)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:446)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1393)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse will indeed move **all** "Maven Dependencies" thus *servlet-api-2.5.jar was also present under the webapp lib which was causing the problem.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to use a newer version of Eclipse and its Maven tools as well.